# Saving a variable, specifically to an incremented div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interactive map I am building that is utilizing an rss feed. The map itself is created in SVG and each 'checkpoint' has the class of `circle` and is incremented to be `circle+k` (circle1, circle2, circle3, etc). My RSS Feed will determine how many of the aforementioned circles will get a class of `filled`, to fill their color in.

I'm doing the above programmatically where I run 2 each functions to increment each div, like this:

```
//increments circle class on the map's dots 
$("#map .circle").each(function(k) {
    $(this).addClass("circle" + (k + 1));
  });


//increments step class on the rss-fed items
$(".gs-rss-feed .hs-rss-item").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("step" + (i + 1));
    //if circle class + number = step class + number, add class filled to circle
    $("#map .circle").eq(i).addClass("filled");  

  });
```

But now I will need to 2 do extra things, access certain information from each RSS post (`title` and `url`). These are both done in classes, so I should be able to get their information like so:

```
//Get link from html
var link = $('.hs-rss-title').attr('href').split('=');
//Get title
var title = $('.hs-rss-title span').html();
```

Then I will need to wrap each of the circles on my map using `.wrap();`

---

My issue where I am having trouble is, how can I scope each of those variables (`title` and `url`) to each specific dot. If I use the above way of saving the vars, then try to use `$("#map .circle").eq(i).wrap("<a href="+link+"></a>");` It ends up only appending the first example, ie: adding the url for the first RSS item to each dot on the map.

Is their a better way I can scope this? Here is my **[codepen](https://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/NgXYxW)**, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use custom data attributes on the elements, and later pull it. like data-title = "Something" data-href="http://www.google.com"

Comment: Since it's technically going to be an rss feed, I can't edit the html structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment yet, so I'll have to post this as an answer..

Can't you just do this inside that second each?

```
//increments step class on the rss-feed items
$(".gs-rss-feed .hs-rss-item").each(function(i) {
  var $rss-item = $(this);
  $rss-item.addClass("step" + (i + 1));
  //if circle class + number = step class + number, add class filled to circle
  var $circle = $("#map .circle").eq(i);
  $circle.addClass("filled");  

  //Get link from html
  var link = $rss-item.find('.hs-rss-title').attr('href').split('=');
  //Get title
  var title = $rss-item.find('.hs-rss-title span').html();

  // here you can wrap $circle and do whatever you want with this link and title
});
```

And not really related to your issue, but why are you splitting the href on =? Apart from missing some slashes I don't see anything in the given href attributes that requires it to be split on =.

Comment: This is perfect, I wasn't using `.find()` which was making it impossible to scope. Those URLS are just dummy links now, but when they come from our RSS I will have to split on `=`. This works great though! Thanks for the quick help!